# How to remove simultaneously both elements in DOM with the same ids in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

What I am trying to do is, when I click on green element I want the purple one with the same id be removed. Now my problem is I can not loop through purple element's id and find the one which match with green one and then remove it from the DOM. I tried to use `querySelectorAll` but it doesn't work with `addEventListener` and when I use `querySelector` it just returns always the first element.So the goal is to remove both elements green and purple that has the same id.

if you see in HTML code inside the ul tag there is another one with the id container actually this is the problem the first ul tag with id main is the original one and the one inside it with id container it will be generated automatically with jQuery plugin if I set any new attribute to class main the class container will copy  it. my goal is to click on green one and delete two elements from DOM. The one which I am clicking and another with same id. is there any way for that?

Has anyone solution for that how to remove simultaneously another element with the same id of clicked element?

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("ul").addEventListener("click", getItem)
})

function getItem(e) {
  let li = e.target.closest(".visible")
  let span = e.target
  let getID = span.attributes.id.value

  console.log("This is visible element", getID)


  if (li) {
    li.remove()
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.hidden {
  border: solid 2px black;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #7d34eb;
}

#container {
  background-color: #3483eb;
  margin-top: 15px
}

.visible {
  border: solid 2px black;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #12a370;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  padding: 50%;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <ul id="main">
    <li class="hidden">
      <span id="1">A</span>
    </li>

    <li class="hidden">
      <span id="2">B</span>
    </li>

    <li class="hidden">
      <span id="3">C</span>
    </li>

    <ul id="container">

      <li class="visible">
        <span id="1">A</span>
      </li>

      <li class="visible">
        <span id="2">B</span>
      </li>

      <li class="visible">
        <span id="3">C</span>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </ul>



</div>
```

Comment: You can't have multiple id's

Comment: ID's must be unique. Do not use the same id twice. That's why it doesn't work. Try using a className instead or a `data-` attribute

Comment: @MihaiT if you see in HTML code inside the ul tag there is another one with the class container now actually this is the problem the first ul tag with class main is the original one and the one inside it with class container it will be generated automatically with jQuery plugin if I set any new attribute to main the container will copy it.

Comment: I don't see any class 'container' . I see an ID 'container'.  But that's not the problem. THe problme is with the duplicate ID's . eg you have two `<span id="1">` . That's not allowed and can cause faulty  functionality ( more like not working as you would expect. but it works correctly from a javascript pov )  just like the one you are describing in your question

Comment: @MihaiT sorry man I said class instead of id ;)  so you mean there is no solution for that? is not possible to take `span` tags which are inside `li`tags with class hidden and then compare them with `span` tag inside `li`tag with class visible and if match remove them. actually this is my idea I am not sure if it is correct.

Comment: In javascript almost everything is possible if you follow some simple rules. Like do not use duplicate ID's :) that's why i said. You could classNames instead or `data-` attributes. Those can be used on multiple elements.

Comment: Just to note that if you ever wanted CSS to use #1 for example it would not work as CSS does not recognise ids beginning with a digit. If you have to use them then CSS will accept [id="1"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed all your spans to div to fill up the LI element. I also changed all `id` to `data-id`, because `id` should be a unique.

EDIT: Based on the comment. In your original post, you added a click listener on the first UL that querySelector returns, which is `#main`. I made that more clear in the code. As the comment, in my answer, suggest, it's better to add a click listener to `ul#container` instead.

EDIT 2: Based on another comment. :P I added code for looping through and removing all elements with matching `data-id`.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  document.querySelector("ul#main").addEventListener("click", getItem);
})

function getItem(e) {
  let divEl = e.target;
  let dataset = divEl.dataset;
  let visibleLi = divEl.parentElement;
  let isVisibleElement = visibleLi.classList.contains('visible');
  let matchingDatasetDivs = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-id="${dataset.id}"]`);

  if (isVisibleElement)
    console.log("This is visible element", dataset.id);

  if (isVisibleElement && matchingDatasetDivs.length) {
    for (let i = 0; i < matchingDatasetDivs.length; i++) {
      let containerLi = matchingDatasetDivs[i].parentElement;
      containerLi.remove();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#main {
  background-color: skyblue;
}

.hidden, .visible {
  border: solid 2px black;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #7d34eb;
}

.visible {
  background-color: #12a370;
}

#container {
  background-color: #3483eb;
  margin-top: 15px
}

li > div {
  position: relative;
  left: 1rem;
  /* padding: 50%; */
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center; /* ADDED */
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

  <ul id="main">
    <li class="hidden">
      <div data-id="1">A</div>
    </li>

    <li class="hidden">
      <div data-id="2">B</div>
    </li>

    <li class="hidden">
      <div data-id="3">C</div>
    </li>

    <ul id="container">

      <li class="visible">
        <div data-id="1">A</div>
      </li>

      <li class="visible">
        <div data-id="2">B</div>
      </li>

      <li class="visible">
        <div data-id="3">C</div>
      </li>

    </ul>

  </ul>



</div>
```

Comment: document.querySelector("ul#container").addEventListener("click", getItem); as per his requirement he needs to click on green elements i think. Isn't it?

Comment: Correct, but OP's original code was to put a listener on the whole thing. I just made that behavior more clear by adding `#main` to the click listener. I would otherwise agree with you.

Comment: @Rickard Elimää if you see in HTML code inside the ul tag there is another one with the id container now actually this is the problem the first ul tag with id main is the original one and the one inside it with id container it will be generated automatically with jQuery plugin if I set any new attribute to main the container will be copied  inside container. my goal is to click on green one and delete two elements from DOM. The one which I am clicking and another with same id. is there any way for that?

Comment: @MaHo OK, so you want to remove both the green and the purple one? That wasn't clear in your original post. You need to update the post, and specifically say that.

Comment: @RickardElimää Yes exactly :) remove both element that has same id. The one I click on it is easy difficult part is to loop through class hidden element and match the id and then remove it.

Comment: @MaHo I see. I edited my post, where it now loops through—and removes—all elements with matching data-id.